# Чтение ecdsa из env выдает: Ошибка декодирования PEM-блока

Tags: golang, tls, .env

Всем добрый день!

в env прописано

```
TLS_KEY=-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----MHcCAQEEIAl3OVDPI+DZga26bSGBoIuYsXHYBMuBdhHqT/zdrYoFoAoGCCqGSM49AwEHoUQDQgAESUiOTkfLNuzOGVolROj356z4pa585PcjLZnCqI8TtfZ8yqMinwbYgFtba0RdYLuKTBZuKHycSxO8irgaegOJYQ==-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----
```

пробывал так

```
TLS_KEY=-----BEGINECPRIVATEKEY-----MHcCAQEEIAl3OVDPI+DZga26bSGBoIuYsXHYBMuBdhHqT/zdrYoFoAoGCCqGSM49AwEHoUQDQgAESUiOTkfLNuzOGVolROj356z4pa585PcjLZnCqI8TtfZ8yqMinwbYgFtba0RdYLuKTBZuKHycSxO8irgaegOJYQ==-----ENDECPRIVATEKEY-----
```

и так

```
TLS_KEY=MHcCAQEEIAl3OVDPI+DZga26bSGBoIuYsXHYBMuBdhHqT/zdrYoFoAoGCCqGSM49AwEHoUQDQgAESUiOTkfLNuzOGVolROj356z4pa585PcjLZnCqI8TtfZ8yqMinwbYgFtba0RdYLuKTBZuKHycSxO8irgaegOJYQ==
```

и так

```
TLS_KEY=MHcCAQEEIAl3OVDPI+DZga26bSGBoIuYsXHYBMuBdhHqT/zdrYoFoAoGCCqGSM49AwEHoUQDQgAESUiOTkfLNuzOGVolROj356z4pa585PcjLZnCqI8TtfZ8yqMinwbYgFtba0RdYLuKTBZuKHycSxO8irgaegOJYQ==
```

и так

```
TLS_KEY=-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
MHcCAQEEIAl3OVDPI+DZga26bSGBoIuYsXHYBMuBdhHqT/zdrYoFoAoGCCqGSM49
AwEHoUQDQgAESUiOTkfLNuzOGVolROj356z4pa585PcjLZnCqI8TtfZ8yqMinwbY
gFtba0RdYLuKTBZuKHycSxO8irgaegOJYQ==
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Но мой код:

```
    err := godotenv.Load("../../../.env")
    envKey := os.Getenv("TLS_KEY")
    envKeyByte := []byte(envKey)
    block, _ := pem.Decode(envKeyByte)
    if block == nil {
        fmt.Println("Ошибка декодирования PEM-блока")
        return
    }
    // Извлекаем приватный ключ из PEM-блока
    privateKey, err := x509.ParseECPrivateKey(block.Bytes)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Ошибка при извлечении приватного ключа:", err)
        return
    }

    // Теперь privateKey содержит приватный ключ в формате ecdsa.PrivateKey
    fmt.Println("Приватный ключ из файла:", privateKey)
```

выдает

```
Ошибка декодирования PEM-блока
```

Тот же ключ из файла читает на ура

`os.Getenv("TLS_KEY")` - точно получает данные

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить?

Comment: Добавление ```envKey = strings.Replace(envKey, "\n", "", -1)``` не помогло

Comment: Даже если я делаю вот так ``` envKey := "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----MHcCAQEEIAl3OVDPI+DZga26bSGBoIuYsXHYBMuBdhHqT/zdrYoFoAoGCCqGSM49AwEHoUQDQgAESUiOTkfLNuzOGVolROj356z4pa585PcjLZnCqI8TtfZ8yqMinwbYgFtba0RdYLuKTBZuKHycSxO8irgaegOJYQ==-----END PRIVATE KEY-----" ``` не срабатывает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как я понимаю, `godotenv` не умеет читать многострочные значения из `.env`, поэтому вам нужно вытянуть PEM файл в одну строку. Например, заменив в `.env` переводы строки на `\n`:

```sh
TLS_KEY=-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----\nMHcCAQEEIAl3OVDPI+DZga26bSGBoIuYsXHYBMuBdhHqT/zdrYoFoAoGCCqGSM49\nAwEHoUQDQgAESUiOTkfLNuzOGVolROj356z4pa585PcjLZnCqI8TtfZ8yqMinwbY\ngFtba0RdYLuKTBZuKHycSxO8irgaegOJYQ==\n-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----
```

В программе нужно эти `\n` превратить обратно в перводы каретки

```
envKey = strings.Replace(envKey, "\\n", "\n", -1)
```

Работает, проверено

```go
package main

import (
    "crypto/x509"
    "encoding/pem"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"

    "github.com/joho/godotenv"
)

func main() {
    err := godotenv.Load(".env")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    envKey := os.Getenv("TLS_KEY")
    fmt.Println("envKey:", envKey)
    envKey = strings.Replace(envKey, "\\n", "\n", -1)
    fmt.Println("envKey:", envKey)
    envKeyByte := []byte(envKey)
    block, _ := pem.Decode(envKeyByte)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    if block == nil {
        fmt.Println("Ошибка декодирования PEM-блока")
        return
    }
    // Извлекаем приватный ключ из PEM-блока
    privateKey, err := x509.ParseECPrivateKey(block.Bytes)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Ошибка при извлечении приватного ключа:", err)
        return
    }

    // Теперь privateKey содержит приватный ключ в формате ecdsa.PrivateKey
    fmt.Println("Приватный ключ из файла:", privateKey)

}
```

результат

```
envKey: -----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----\nMHcCAQEEIAl3OVDPI+DZga26bSGBoIuYsXHYBMuBdhHqT/zdrYoFoAoGCCqGSM49\nAwEHoUQDQgAESUiOTkfLNuzOGVolROj356z4pa585PcjLZnCqI8TtfZ8yqMinwbY\ngFtba0RdYLuKTBZuKHycSxO8irgaegOJYQ==\n-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----
envKey: -----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
MHcCAQEEIAl3OVDPI+DZga26bSGBoIuYsXHYBMuBdhHqT/zdrYoFoAoGCCqGSM49
AwEHoUQDQgAESUiOTkfLNuzOGVolROj356z4pa585PcjLZnCqI8TtfZ8yqMinwbY
gFtba0RdYLuKTBZuKHycSxO8irgaegOJYQ==
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----
Приватный ключ из файла: &{{0xf49e20 33147033093660344646645925386663119719432505505321643683373607924858793211382 56444822249450449874350353117301656088240469555926601698131529356926452468065} 4281466016109929524467996645554519299923541051122177355964790875171320596997}
```